# Tradingview alerts using Tradingview technical signals

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

I have a bot installed here

https://mydomain/coin/trade.php

which can receive signal from Trading View webhook .
I would send to my webhook trading view technical signals when the trading view 1 minute timeframe is a strong buy (as in the image below). Is it possible ? And how should I set the webhook link to send this signal ?.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has just been released: [The New Built-in Pine Indicator — Technical Ratings](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/the-new-built-in-pine-indicator-technical-ratings-24157/)

I think you can now build what you intended.
You can add alerts on them, which you can then send to your bot via webhooks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done.
You just need to setup an alert for your signal, and have it send a custom message to your webhook url `https://mydomain/coin/trade.php`.
That custom message must be in a format that your bot can understand and process.
The message can be sent in plain text or JSON.
It's really very straightforward. See [About webhooks](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000529348-about-webhooks/).
You can also put [variables into the alert message](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000531021-how-to-use-a-variable-value-in-alert/).
Some examples can be found in the [Our New Alerts Allow for Dynamic Messages](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/our-new-alerts-allow-for-dynamic-messages-22588/) blog post.

Comment: I know the weekhooks of course, and I already use them to send signals to my php bots using php binance API. My Question is how to send to the webhook TV signals as in the image above using the webhooks, for example timeframe 1 minute e.g with TV  BUY signal (Summary signal).

Comment: I do not want send signal from studies or strategies (I am already doing it) , I am just curios how to send the TV signals in the image above .

Comment: Ah, ok. Now I understand what you mean. Those built-in metrics cannot be used to send signals to a webhook afaik. Only objects that you can put an alert on can do that. Sorry to dissapoint you.

Comment: However, maybe you could program it in Pine. Those gauges are built using the Oscillators and Moving Averages that are shown below. If you could find out the values that makes them switch to another Signal, then you could calculate it yourself and put an alert on that, which you can then use in your webhook.

Comment: Thank you , I know this too, however why I should do the work since TV has already these signal ready to be used , it's a shame that these signals cannot be used with an alert. However in 3commas DCAbots can be setup using exactly these TV signals so I guess how can  3commas DCAbots uses them .

Comment: That's interesting. Could you point me to a DCAbot that uses these TV signals please? I created a 3commas account, but can't see the option to choose those signals when creating a bot.

Comment: 3commas bots. When you create the DCAbot you can choose to use Trading view signals above (strong, strong buy) on a selected timeframe .

Comment: https://3commas.io/blog/dca-bots-creating-a-futures-dca-bot-using-tradingview-buy-sell-signals , look the screenshot 7

Comment: Indeed. I have no idea how they do that. I've just sent an email to 3comma's to ask how they do it. Will let you know when they reply.

Comment: Did some back-and-forth mailing with them. First they said they use a TradingView API for that, but such an API does not exists. Then it became clear that they're using some sort of web scraper to get the values. I realize this doesn't solve your problem, but that's the answer I got.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually take a snap shot and then send the picture created using sendPhoto feature via api unless there is a link to the image already if you right click on the object and can extract the link the you can use send message feature via api.

Hope this helps